# Sitecore/xDB/MongoDB arbiter instance receiving application account connection attempts

Tags: mongodb, sitecore, sitecore8

I have a Sitecore 8 test environment with three mongo 2.6.5 instances for xDB. These are configured as a replication set using a keyfile with two servers 'mongotest1' & 'mongotest2' and one arbiter 'mongotest3'. A non-admin account has been createdin mongo for the web application, stored in the  admin database with readWrite permissions in all five xDB databases. My sitecore connection strings are in the format:

```
connectionString="mongodb://webapp:password@mongotest1:27018,mongotest2.local:27019/sc8-tracking-history?replicaSet=repSet1&amp;authSource=admin
```

Note that the arbiter is not specified in the connection string, which is normal.

rs.status() gives the following, which looks correct:

```
"date" : ISODate("2015-07-23T16:47:08Z"),
"myState" : 2,
"syncingTo" : "mongotest1.local:27018",
"members" : [
        {
                "_id" : 0,
                "name" : "mongotest1.local:27018",
                "health" : 1,
                "state" : 1,
                "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                "uptime" : 93,
                "optime" : Timestamp(1437668096, 1),
                "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-07-23T16:14:56Z"),
                "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-07-23T16:47:07Z"),
                "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-07-23T16:47:08Z"),
                "pingMs" : 0,
                "electionTime" : Timestamp(1437669503, 1),
                "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-07-23T16:38:23Z")
        },
        {
                "_id" : 1,
                "name" : "mongotest2.local:27019",
                "health" : 1,
                "state" : 2,
                "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                "uptime" : 93,
                "optime" : Timestamp(1437668096, 1),
                "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-07-23T16:14:56Z"),
                "infoMessage" : "syncing to: mongotest1.local:27018",
                "self" : true
        },
        {
                "_id" : 2,
                "name" : "mongotest3.local:27020",
                "health" : 1,
                "state" : 7,
                "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                "uptime" : 91,
                "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-07-23T16:47:07Z"),
                "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-07-23T16:47:07Z"),
                "pingMs" : 0
        }
],
"ok" : 1
```

When the three mongo instances are started, normal log output is observed. However, after the Sitecore web application connects to mongo I see connection attempts using the 'webapp' account to the arbiter service which fail because the arbiter does not hold an admin database with any user accounts defined. The frequency of this increases if I shutdown mongotest1 and mongotest2 instances. If I shutdown Sitecore, the connection attempts stop.

```
2015-07-23T18:02:42.741+0100 [conn699] end connection 127.0.0.1:62206 (2 connections now open)
2015-07-23T18:02:43.610+0100 [conn689] end connection 127.0.0.1:62193 (1 connection now open)
2015-07-23T18:02:43.611+0100 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62207 #700 (3 connections now open)
2015-07-23T18:02:43.613+0100 [conn700]  authenticate db: local { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "__system", key: "xxx" }
2015-07-23T18:02:43.890+0100 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62208 #701 (3 connections now open)
2015-07-23T18:02:43.891+0100 [conn701]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, user: "webapp", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-07-23T18:02:43.891+0100 [conn701] Failed to authenticate webapp@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed UserNotFound Could not find
 user webapp@admin
```

Why is this happening? The arbiter shouldn't be receiving any connection attempts from clients. Its as if the replica set is sharing the arbiter connection to the web application which then invokes some connection attempts.

Comment: First of all, this problem is definitely NOT specific to Sitecore or XDB.
"The arbiter shouldn't be receiving any connection attempts from clients." – in general, this isn't true. Arbiters can still receive connections from clients that want to use them as seed hosts (i.e. for receiving information about the cluster). In your case, I would grant the application the rights to connect, and then you'll see what exactly it attempts to do on the arbiter server. If it's just querying replica set metadata, it's fine. If if attempts to read XDB data, there is probably a defect in the C# MongoDB driver

Comment: Per @DmytroShevchenko's comments - the drivers _do_ get information about the cluster from Mongo directly.  Further, they will make connections based on the server info in the rs.config() despite your connection string.  It's important that Sitecore can reach all the various Mongos based on the names as configured in the replica set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known c-sharp driver issue, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-851

Some aspects of the situation are Sitecore release specific - the bundled driver (v1.8.3.9) seems to slightly predate the driver released with v2.6.5, which meant it predated the fix.

Sitecore 8 update 5 updates Mongo and includes the fix. Alternatively a minimal fix can be achieved by [upgrading the bundled MongoDB.Driver.dll to v1.9](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/releases/download/v1.9.0/CSharpDriver-1.9.zip) and adding an assembly redirect to web.config.

I blogged a more verbose version of this answer at http://blog.paulgeorge.co.uk/2016/01/26/sitecore-mongo-arbiter-shows-failed-authentication-attempts/